# Manage Maximize functions for dual screen

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm developing an application with multiples windows that is compatible with multi-screen. I have made my own title bar for all the windows.

My title bar :

```
<Grid x:Class="TitleBar"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"
      MouseLeftButtonDown="gridBar_MouseLeftButtonDown"
      x:Name="titleBar">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" [...]/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="bttnClose" [...]/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="buttonMinimize" [...]/>
</Grid>
```

With the function :

```
private void gridBar_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Window.GetWindow(this) != null)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2) // double click handle
        {
            if (Window.GetWindow(this).WindowState == WindowState.Normal)                   
                Window.GetWindow(this).WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            else
                Window.GetWindow(this).WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        try
        {
            Window.GetWindow(this).DragMove();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

All my windows are not re-sizable (Max/Min Height and Width are equals) except the main windows. So I want to manage the full screen to multi screen environment.

I added this on my `MainWindow` Class:

```
protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        var hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
        var currentMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
        var primaryMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMERTY);
        var isInPrimary = currentMonitor == primaryMonitor;

        // Don't want to hide the taskbar
        if (isInPrimary)
            this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        else
            this.MaxHeight = Double.PositiveInfinity;
    }
    base.OnStateChanged(e);
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMERTY = 0x00000001;
    public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, Int32 flags);
}
```

It works almost but when I set the `MaxHeight`, it doesn't refresh the actual `Height`. I had to maximize twice by screen to have the correct size.

Can you help me ?

Comment: And if the taskbar is on left or right or also displayed on secondary monitors?

Comment: It doesn't work in that case :-(. This code is very basic and consider just one case. But it's regrettable that .NET doesn't provide function to manage active area and screen easily (or I have not found it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, but maybe not the best one :

```
private void Maximize()
{
    var hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
    var currentMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    var primaryMonitor = NativeMethods.MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMERTY);
    var isInPrimary = currentMonitor == primaryMonitor;

    // Don't want to hide the taskbar
    if (isInPrimary)
        this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
    else
        this.MaxHeight = Double.PositiveInfinity;
}

protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && DoRefresh)
    {
        DoRefresh = false;
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        Maximize();
        DoRefresh = true;
    }
}
```

Problem was that changing Height or MaxHeight on maximized Windows has no effect. When the status change to Maximized I force it to normal and change MaxHeight. After that I reset status to maximized. I'v created bool `DoRefresh` to avoid infinite loops.